# Fail to install boost-1.70.0 via yum for AWS jupyter terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, boost, yum

I'm working with AWS jupyter notebook, and I need to have boost installed. When installing with yum, the version of boost installed is 1.54.0. However, I need to have version 1.70.0. When I try to specify a version with yum, I have an error.

```
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requires, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper, versionlock
amzn-main                                                                                           
amzn-updates                                                                                        
No package boost-1.70.0 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Please advise, how to install boost 1.70.0 in this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Steps to follow:

1) `wget -c https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.70.0/source/boost_1_70_0.tar.gz -O - | sudo tar -xz -C /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/` will download boost library to /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/ folder on the AWS

2) add the correct path references to build.sh or any other in order to be able to locate boost library